# How to Click "OK" or "Cancel" button on Select a certificate to authenticate pop up in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm getting a "Select a certificate to authenticate" pop up window when I launch application, I tried keyboard event like pressing Enter Key to select pop up, but it's not working. is there any way to select OK button ?

```html
const playwright = require('playwright');

browser = await playwright['chromium'].launch({ headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized', '--ignore-certificate-errors'] })
        const context = await browser.newContext({ viewport: null });
        const page = await context.newPage();
        await page.goto(domain);
        await page.waitForTimeout(6000)
        await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is an upstream feature request on Playwright side, its not yet implemented: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1799